# Polynomial Division - General Techniques + Specific Technique to Solve this Question

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I'm trying to determine how to divide this polynomial. It goes from

$$\frac{1 - (n+1)^2x^n + n(n+2)x^{n+1}}{-2(1-x)}$$

to
$$\frac{-n(n+1)^2 x^{n-1} + n(n+1)(n+2)x^n}{2}.$$

This division of $-(1-x)$ between these lines is messing with me; I've looked at it for a while and I just can't figure it out. I'm not the best with polynomial manipulation but this one is particularly difficult.

Could you please show the steps you took to solve this?
I've run it through a few online polynomial simplifiers to no avail.
I'm not looking to evaluate it at the limit, I know the answer to that. I'd just like to figure out how to divide it.
Also, what are general tips for difficult polynomial manipulation?

Comment: Hint: $\,n(n+2)=(n+1)^2-1\,$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems they have used L'Hôpitals rule here to differentiate the numerator and the denominator with respect to x.

In general with problems involving invoking that rule, you can use it repeatedly until the denominator does not go to zero.